# android: I want a(n) (Image)Button with two images on it

Tags: android, xml, button, drawable, imagebutton

I am designing a calculator in android, and for that I need buttons with two images on them, one image for the button main function and the other for the button second function. I cant collapse them into one image because those two functions of the button have to be separately replacable.
Currently I 'solved' this with coding a layer-list and using it as the android:src for an ImageButton, but this seems clumsy and has issues when resizing.

Is there a better solution?

I am trying to stick with xml, by the way

Comment: consider editing your tags and mention what language/tools you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround/a better ansatz. Instead of using ImageButton with two images, I am now using a custom font that contains vector images as characters, and write with the font into a normal Button.